# Why does this rule with `not` always return false?

Tags: prolog, negation

I have this prolog file:

```
daughter(anna, vera).
daughter(vera, oleg).
daughter(olga, pavel).
daughter(olga, alla).
daughter(alla, lidia).
man(oleg).
man(victor).
man(pavel).
not(P) :- (call(P) -> fail ; true).
woman(X) :- not(man(X)).
```

`?- woman(X).` always returns false. `?- man(X).` returns all three male entries though.
I also tried `woman(X) :- \+man(X).` but certain syntax is not the problem it seems.

If I try to check a certain person it works: `?- woman(anna).` returns true.

I'm quite new to prolog and can't even suggest what is wrong here.

UPD. I want all people who are not men to be classified as men. The question is - why can't I do `woman(X)` and get all non-men?

```
?- woman(anna).
true.

?- woman(X).
false.

?- man(X).
X = oleg ;
X = victor ;
X = pavel.
```

UPD2. Solution

The problem was caused by [floundering](https://github.com/dtonhofer/prolog_notes/blob/master/other_notes/about_negation/floundering.md) as was pointed out in the comments. I needed `woman(X)` rule to implement this rule: `mothers_names(X, Y) :- not(man(X)), daughter(Y,X).`

In a nutshell, inverting the query works: `mothers_names(X, Y) :- daughter(Y,X), not(man(X)).` because first predicate makes X in `not(man(X))` limited to several values.

Comment: `woman(peter)` also succeeds. check out "closed world assumption" and "negation as failure".

Comment: yep, it's correct behavior because ```peter``` is not listed as a man. The way this code works is "woman is everyone who is not a man". For example, ```woman(oleg)``` returns false.

Comment: if you know the answer, what is the question? :) do you want `woman(lidia)` to succeed? what about `woman(maria)`?

Comment: In particular, **never call a predicate behind the `not` operator (better written as `\+`) when an unbound variable is involved**. As in `woman(X)`: _"Are there any women"?_ But Prolog will test "`\+ man(X)` _"There are women ... if there are no men"_ (a very contemporary stance I might add). This is not what you want. See: [floundering](https://github.com/dtonhofer/prolog_notes/blob/master/other_notes/about_negation/floundering.md). This Prolog finesse should have been "fixed" a couple of decades ago, but progress in logic pgr is not the fastest at this point in the history of computing.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer thanks a lot, floundering was the problem indeed

Comment: @DavidTonhofer: Why don't you just offer `not(G_0) :- when(ground(G_0), \+ man(G_0))` instead of complaining? And yes, that definition does flounder from time to time, but the answers are correct (at least in systems that do show all involved constraints like SICStus or Scryer).

Comment: "I needed `woman(X)` rule to implement this rule: `mothers_names(X, Y) :- not(man(X)), daughter(Y,X).`" so why did you not include this crucial tidbit in the question from the start?